# How can I delete an option from a listbox and having that reflect in a text file?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, file-writing

I have a listbox of saved values that are also saved into a .txt file. I can delete options in the listbox just fine, but I am having a hard time finding out how to reflect the deleted values in its .txt file.

My values are set up to be a dictionary and my options are:

Option 1: I could read the text file as a dictionary and remove the key that corresponds to the selected listbox.

Option 2: I could, after deleting the selected listbox, rewrite the .txt to include every remaining listbox.

edit: To clarify, I have a listbox. This listbox is made from contents in a .txt. I have a button to delete an option in the listbox. I need the button to delete the value in the .txt too, but I am having troubles with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest would be to open file first with read persmission and after all, open it again with write permission and write full content

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  1) delete items from listbox and then update the text file? 2) delele items in the text file and then update the listbox? Which one do you want?

Comment: @kosciej16 how would I be able to collect the data from the current listbox options? I've had no luck with listbox.get() so far, and listbox.curselection() won't work because I need every listbox option.

Comment: @acw1668 I have a button to delete listbox options. Now I need the updated listbox to reflect its options in an updated .txt

Comment: You can use `listbox.get(0, 'end')` to get all the items in the listbox.

Comment: @acw1668 that worked! I was able to write the file again in a for loop with this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @acw1668

```
for index in listbox.curselection():           #Set the current selection to be deleted
    listbox.delete(index)

with open("saved.txt","w") as f:               #Takes the new listbox, without 
     for index in listbox.get(0, END):         #deleted item, and rewrote   
        f.write(index)                            #the saved.txt
```